# bash echo command

Tags: bash, echo

I would like to know why it display only `tomate` and not both words.

```
$ a="tomate" ; echo $a
tomate
$ (a="poivron" ; echo $a)
poivron
$ echo $a
tomate
```

Comment: The second command is in a subshell https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/subshells.html

Comment: thank, now i know.

Comment: why were you expecting both words to print?

Comment: it was a question from an exercice. But now i understand why it print only the first word.